# Why invoking of most JPA Repositpry methods through Class Implementing ContraintValidator during Save causing HH000099: Assertion Failure?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, validation, jpa

I have a simple field level custom validator that implements ContraintValidator. It makes use of JPA Repository to call
1. findById(), and
2. count()
within isValid method.
Call to findById() is successful. However, invoking count() method causes an error, 
"ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id"

I have tried switching JPA Repository just to check if it was something specific for that repository but the behaviour is same across all repositories.
I have tried making calls to other JPA methods such as findIfExists, findAll, but all of them are causing same error.
The issue is that it complains about null id, when it is expected to be blank as it is call to Save.

```
    public class CountValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Counter, String> {

    private AreaRepository areaRepository;

    public CountValidator(AreaRepository areaRepository) {
           this.areaRepository = areaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Counter constraint) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { 
           boolean isValid = false;
           try {
           // Simple check to see of repository is reachable (TO BE DELETED)
           Area area = areaRepository.findById(1L).get();
           // Count number of records in Area table.
           long count = areaRepository.count();
           if (count < 3) {
                   isValid = true;
           }
           } catch (Exception e) {
                   System.out.println(e);
           }
           return isValid;
     }

   }
```

It was expected that on first iteration variable count will be 0, but is errors have triggering count() call. Also, why would call to findById work, but not call other methods. As a result, the insertion call (save) is just being rolled back.

UPDATE - Area

```
    @Audited
    @Entity
    @Counter
    public class Area {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5058628890621461831L;

            @Id
            @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;

            @NotBlank
            @Size(max = 50)
            @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
            private String name;

            public Area() {}

            public String getName() {
                   return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                    this.name = name;
            }

    }
```

Comment: How does your Area  look like?

Comment: Hi Simon, added Area Entity for visbility